# How come for(var i in arguments) doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, loops, arguments, key-value

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work:

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("result").value=add(1,2);
}
function add(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i in arguments)
        sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

This outputs `001`. Why?

Comment: @SurrealDreams What does it matter? Please try to be constructive.

Comment: No homework, just new to javascript

Comment: Just asking, albeit cheekily.  I tend to construct an answer differently depending on the audience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are iterating keys, do this:

```
function add(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i in arguments)
        sum += arguments[i];
    return sum;
}
```

More specifically, the keys are strings, `"0"` and `"1"`, thus your response which is the concatenation of your initial 0, and subsequent keys.

Also, if you are interested in javascript on modern platforms, the following is very clear and concise.

```
function add(){
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
        return a+b;
    });
}
console.log(add(1,2));
```

Comment: @Justin984: it's better form to use `for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)` instead since `for (var i in arguments` will iterate all properties of `arguments`, not just the indices.

Comment: @tjameson Can you give an example of what can go wrong? I'm not sure what you mean by iterating all properties.

Comment: @matt3141 Thanks for explaining this, unfortunately I'm a little too green for the second example to make much sense yet :P

Comment: @Justin984 I encourage you to take a look at `Array#reduce`, `Array#map`, etc. You can probably find a good article with them labeled as a group as "Functional JavaScript"

Comment: @Justin984 - You probably won't notice anything with `arguments`, any other object that has a prototype chain could cause problems. See [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and [Douglas Crockford's tips](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) (his style is sometimes overly strict, but safe).

Comment: @Justin984 - For the functions on Array, see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It's near the middle under methods, specifically accessor methods.

Comment: @tjameson If I'm not mistaken, the arguments object also has a prototype chain, it inherits from Object.prototype.

Comment: @Justin984 Another problem with a `for...in` loop with `arguments` is that it doesn't seem to work in old IE. `arguments` is an array (in newer browsers) and an array-like object in older...normal `for` loops should be used to iterate over them.

Comment: @bfavaretto - I didn't notice anything weird in some tests on FF, but Chrome may be different. The short of the matter is that it can't be guaranteed and isn't a good pattern, especially since `for (;;)` works more reliably.

Comment: @tjameson Agreed, `for(;;)` is the right kind of loop for the arguments object. I tested in Chrome, and properties added to Object.prototype do show in a `for..in` loop over `arguments`.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
function add(){
    var sum = 0, x = 0;
    for(var i in arguments){
        //the key is an index
        if(!arguments.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        // try converting argument[i] to a number
        x = +arguments[i];

        // check if argument is a valid number 
        if(!isNaN(x)) {
            sum += x;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vg4Nq/

Comment: You don't really need `parseInt` here.

Comment: Why this: `typeof x != typeof NaN` ? The `typeof NaN` will always be `"number"`, and `typeof x` will also always be `"number"`, so the condition will never be met.

Comment: @matt3141 thanks for the update. Also I have moved the check for `hasOwnProperty` before `parseInt` as we had accessed `arguments[i]` already

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Remember to provide the radix parameter to `parseInt`. And checking `if(isNaN(x))` means that you're checking that `x` is **not** a number...so you need to add `!`. I added both. Hopefully that's okay and is correct :)

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I also just updated to actually convert to a number (not parse it...which can have problems, like if the value "5p" gets passed somehow), and added a demo

Comment: Also, this form of looping over `arguments` in old IE doesn't work :( Just another reason not to use `for...in` on arrays and array-like objects

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility.

```
function add() {
    var numbers = [].slice.call(arguments),
        sum = 0;

    do {
        sum += numbers.shift();
    } while (isFinite(sum) && numbers.length);

    return +sum;
}

console.log(add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3d8wm/)</kbd>

Update: This is more cross browser than `reduce`. We can also improve on this if we wish to do a little more checking of the data.

```
function add1() {
    var numbers = [].slice.call(arguments),
        sum = 0,
        x;

    do {
        x = numbers.shift();
        sum += (typeof x === "number" ? x : NaN);
    } while (isFinite(sum) && numbers.length);

    return +sum;
}

console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ""));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "0xA"));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NaN));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Infinity));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -Infinity));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, true));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, false));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, []));
console.log("add1", add1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, {}));
```

And we can compare that with no checking

```
function add2() {
    return [].reduce.call(arguments, function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
}

console.log("add1", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
console.log("add1", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ""));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "0xA"));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NaN));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Infinity));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -Infinity));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, true));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, false));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, []));
console.log("add2", add2(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, {}));
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/hDSjf/)</kbd>

And how is the performance affected by these extra checks that were introduced?

Let's see, <kbd>[jsperf](http://jsperf.com/add-reduce-vs-slice-with-extra-checks)</kbd>

<s>Feel free to add the other solutions to the performance test.</s> - I added the others.

Anyway, I would avoid using `for..in` when looping through an `arguments` object (to avoid looping through any methods that may have been attached to `arguments`) and would choose any of the other usual `Array` looping methods: `for`, `while`, `forEach` or `reduce`

See relevance: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)